# Why can I re-assign a const if you do import * as name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, import, export, constants, immutability

Why is it possible to re-assign to a const if I import it as an entire module's contents? Is it supposed to work like this? I thought const is supposed to be immutable.

For example:

```
// constants.js
export const APPLE = 'apple';

// app.js
import { APPLE } from 'constants.js';
import * as constants from 'constants.js';

constants.APPLE = 'banana';
console.log(APPLE);

//output
banana;
```

I can't re-assign the const `APPLE` directly, but I can re-assign `constants.APPLE` which also gives `APPLE` a new value.

When I print out `constants` in Chrome, I get the output below.

```
//output of constants
{APPLE: "apple", __esModule: true}
  APPLE: "banana"
  __esModule: true
  __proto__: Object
```

Why does the values of `APPLE` differ?

Comment: Regarding to "I thought const is supposed to be immutable". const is mutable, but can not be redeclared or reassigned.